# Javascript Promise from scratch

Tags: javascript, promise

I got an error writing a basic promise from scratch and don't know why `this.status` produces an error

```js
class Promisify {
  constructor(fn) {
    this.status = 0; // 0 = unfulfilled, 1 = resolved, 2 = rejected
    this.result = undefined;
    this.error = undefined;
    this.thenFns = [];
    this.catchFns = [];
    this.finallyFn = undefined;

    try {
      fn(this._resolve, this._reject);
    } catch (e) {
      this._reject(e);
    }
  }


  // public methods
  then(fn) {
    this.thenFns.push(fn);
    this._doThen();
    return this;
  }

  catch(fn) {
    this.catchFns.push(fn);
    this._doCatch();
    return this;
  };
  
  finally(fn) {
    this.finallyFn = fn;
    return this;
  }

  // private methods
  _doThen() {
    if (this.status === 1) {
      while(this.thenFns.length) {
        this.thenFns.shift()(this.result);
      }
    }
  }

  _doCatch() {
    if (this.status === 2) {
      if (this.catchFns.length === 0) {
        console.error('uncaught error')
      }
      while(this.catchFns.length) {
        this.catchFns.shift()(this.error);
      }
    }
  }

  _resolve(r) {
    if(this.status) 
      throw Error('cannot resolve, already handled');
    this.status = 1;
    this.result = r;
    this._doThen();
  }
  
  _reject(e) {
    if (this.status) throw Error('cannot reject, already handled');
    this.status = 2;
    this.error = e;
    this._doCatch();
  }
}
```

Comment: I applaud this effort. Good idea. One tip after you fixed this issue, is that `then()` and `catch()` should not return `this`. They should return a new promise that resolves into the return value of the callback passed to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass your functions for someone else to call with

```
 fn(this._resolve, this._reject);
```

and have `this` point to your promise object when they are called, you need to bind them explicitly:

```
  fn(this._resolve.bind(this), this._reject.bind(this));
```

```js
class Promisify {
   constructor(fn) {
     this.status = 0; // 0 = unfulfilled, 1 = resolved, 2 = rejected
     this.result = undefined;
     this.error = undefined;
     this.thenFns = [];
     this.catchFns = [];
     this.finallyFn = undefined;
 
     try {
       fn(this._resolve.bind(this), this._reject.bind(this));
     } catch (e) {
       this._reject(e);
     }
   }
 
   // public methods
   then(fn) {
     this.thenFns.push(fn);
     this._doThen();
     return this;
   }
 
   catch(fn) {
     this.catchFns.push(fn);
     this._doCatch();
     return this;
   };
   
   finally(fn) {
     this.finallyFn = fn;
     return this;
   }
 
   // private methods
   _doThen() {
     if (this.status === 1) {
       while(this.thenFns.length) {
         this.thenFns.shift()(this.result);
       }
     }
   }
 
   _doCatch() {
     if (this.status === 2) {
       if (this.catchFns.length === 0) {
         console.error('uncaught error')
       }
       while(this.catchFns.length) {
         this.catchFns.shift()(this.error);
       }
     }
   }
 
   _resolve(r) {
     if(this.status) 
       throw Error('cannot resolve, already handled');
     this.status = 1;
     this.result = r;
     this._doThen();
   }
   
   _reject(e) {
     if (this.status) throw Error('cannot reject, already handled');
     this.status = 2;
     this.error = e;
     this._doCatch();
   }
 }
 

 const demo = new Promisify((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(function() {
     resolve('Howdy!')
   }, 1000);
 });
 
 demo
.then(val => console.log("Demo Value in Then!!", val))
.catch(console.error) //Should throw an error.
.then(val => console.log("Second then!"))
.catch((err) => {
    throw new Error('error', err);
})
.finally(val => console.log("Executed Finally"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple promise build from scratch

```
class Promisify 
{
  constructor(fn)
  {
    this._function1 = fn; 
  }

  finally()
  {
    console.log('finally executed');
  }

  catch(error)
  {
    console.log('catch executed');
    return this;
  }

  then(resolve, reject)
  {
    try
    {
      this._function1(resolve, reject);  
      return this;
    }
    catch(err)
    {
       this.catch(err);
       return this;
    }

    this.finally();

  }

}

let promise = new Promisify(function(resolve, reject)
{
    console.log('promise executed');

    resolve('resolved');
})

promise
.then(function(input)
{
   console.log(input);
})
.then(function(input)
{
   console.log('second then');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because of scoping.you are calling resolve and reject from new Promise function call which has their own scope.

In this case you need to bind your Promisify class object to resolve and reject method it will work out, mainly this issue is occurring because of `'this'`